# Drag and Drop Items from Listview into Activity

Tags: android, android-listview

In my app, I want the user to be able to follow this list of instructions to be able to put a link to their installed android apps into a widget that I am creating.

In the widget, when the user taps the widget it opens up a new activity which contains all of their apps. To add new app links to that activity, I want the user to be able to pull out a kind of scrolling tab that would hold a list of all of their applications they have on their device (I already know how to do this). The user would then be able to press and hold on a app from that listview and then drag it into the droppable area in the widget that would hold their app. Please note the picture below to get a better idea of what I mean (sorry for poor quality):

[image: Idea]

How could I turn a listview object into something that is able to do this? I would have to make the listview have a touch listener attribute and then make the droppable area have a drag event, that much I am sure of (somewhat from just looking around on how to make things drag and droppable).

How could I do this? Any ideas or comments on improvements are appreciated!

Comment: http://pencil.evolus.vn/   great open source app for wireframing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `setOnItemLongClickListener` to set a listener waiting for a long click then when it is fired begin the drag process.

Comment: I've started a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19416693/drag-and-drop-listview-item-from-long-click-listener) if you could help me to get started on how to do that, I would appreciate it. :)