# Drag and Drop Listview Item From Long Click Listener

Tags: android

I have a list view of all the users installed applications and want the user to be able to drag and drop each item in the list view to another activity by using the **setOnItemLongClickListener**. Here is my current coding:

```
Drag_and_Drop_App.java (snippet):

// implement event when an item on list view is selected via long-click for drag and drop
mListAppInfo.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView parent, View view,
            int pos, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // get the list adapter
        AppInfoAdapter appInfoAdapter = (AppInfoAdapter)parent.getAdapter();
        // get selected item on the list
        ApplicationInfo appInfo = (ApplicationInfo)appInfoAdapter.getItem(pos);
        // launch the selected application
        Utilities.launchApp(parent.getContext(), getPackageManager(), appInfo.packageName);
        return true;
    }


});
}
}
```

As you can see, I just have it set up when the user long clicks an item in the list, the item opens up (the applications starts). However, since I want to start the drag sequence, how would I go about doing this? I've looked at the drag and drop tutorial [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html), so I guess better questions would be:

1. Do I need to assign an ID to the listview items?
2. When the user long clicks an item, how could I start the drag process?

   -Could I just create a Drag Activity class and then start a new intent of that class?

   -Since I have already made it so that when the item is longclicked, something happens (like assigning a longclicklistener), could I just create these two classes that go along with it?

(Provided by tutorial ((link above)) )

```
private final class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
  public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
  if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
    DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
    view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
    view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
}

class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {
Drawable enterShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_droptarget);
Drawable normalShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape);

@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
  int action = event.getAction();
  switch (event.getAction()) {
  case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
    // do nothing
    break;
  case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
    v.setBackgroundDrawable(enterShape);
    break;
  case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
    v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
    break;
  case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
    // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup
    View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
    ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
    owner.removeView(view);
    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;
    container.addView(view);
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    break;
  case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
    v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
  default:
    break;
  }
  return true;
}
}
}
```

I collect and display the users installed applications in my class here:

```
   public static List getInstalledApplication(Context c) {
return c.getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
}
```

I have this listview set up in a sliding drawer, and want the user to be able to drag and drop a list item to a different activity outside of the drawer.

Am I thinking about this the correct way?